# Why do I get an "unmet dependencies" error when trying to install WINE?

Tags: apt, wine

When trying to install WINE (`sudo apt-get install wine`) I get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Google does tell me that apparently this has something to to with `ia32-libs`, but I cannot find out how to do to fix the dependencies or if I need to (manually?) install something else.

I have added `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` to my repositories.

`sudo apt-get install wine1.5`gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1+pulse17)
```

`sudo apt-get install wine1.5-i386`gives me

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: gettext:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify whether you have a x32 or x64 system. This error sounds like `dpkg` going dodgy on multiarch.

Comment: possible duplicated: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with broken dependencies when trying to install wine and acroread, and a complaint when trying to install ia32-libs-multiarch, just after upgrading to 12.04 from 11.04 (passing over 11.10). It seems that some ppa's I had in 11.04 installed newer versions of applications in the system. After upgrading, the remains of these apps seemed to do some mess in the dependencies.

The solution that seems to work (until now), was found on a german ubuntu board ([http://forum.ubuntuusers.de](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/paketabhaengigkeit-mit-ia32-libs-kann-nicht-au/2/), posts from user Lasall):

First a downgrade is required and done with the following:
create the 'preferences' file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=precise*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

enter `:wq` to write the file. Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000.

Then you may downgrade the offending applications with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then you may install packages that complained about dependencies, like
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`, or `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`.

Finally, you should remove the file you just created:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences
```

because else no new updates would be found.

Hope this helps you too!

Comment: Hah! This fixed a bug I've had with installing Wine in 12.10. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

## Run

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/base-files
```

### Paste & Save

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=precise*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

### Downgrade Apps Causing The Error

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### Now We Can Install Wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

### Finally, remove the file you created

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/base-files
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of JFB's answer. If it is different, please show us how it differs.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Wine by using the Ubuntu Software Center to see if the problem is solved.

You can find some useful help resources for Wine at www.winehq.org/help/, and you can
learn more about alternatives to Wine at [winehq.org](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/alternatives.)

Comment: That does not work, either. It gives about the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in 13.04 64 bit is following David Leo's answer with a small modification to base-files:

Package: *
Pin: release a=**raring***
Pin-Priority: 2012