# Install packages and dependencies without Internet connection

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and my problem is that I don't have any Internet connection and I want to use wine, MS OFFICE, Turbo C++, DOS BOX, and many more applications that are required to me. But Ubuntu needs to download dependencies so is there any package to install all the dependencies that are required for Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138530/why-do-i-get-an-unmet-dependencies-error-when-trying-to-install-wine

Answer (score 0):

Installing Wine and other software in ubuntu is complicated without any Internet connection. This link seems have same problem with yours and maybe help you: [askubuntu-How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: Ya I am trying since last 4 days but the keryx is saying that project needs to be created how do i create project when I am using windows. See right now m using keryx i want to add my computer name while adding it says only Debian based distros can be added even though I am typing Ubuntu 12.04 in the text box. and I am using one of my friends lap top so will you please tell me the steps precisely so that i can download packages and dependencies efficiently.