# I have problem and I cant install someone help me packages have unmet dependencies: wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386?

Tags: wine

[image]

I marked the problem i cant install with ubuntu center and Synaptic i cant repair !!

The following packages have unmet dependencies: wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1: 1.6.1-0ubuntu1 PPA1 ~ ~ precise1) but it is not installable E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

64 bit 12.04LTS

and tried update to ubuntu 14.04 but I cant update too..

Comment: Seems that you have some incompatible PPA installed. Please tell which PPA you have installed in your system. Have you ever done an upgrade without purging all the PPA before?

Comment: What do you get when you run sudo apt-get install wine1.6?

Comment: @Rmano I was installed wine only and I not updated and after I try install moka theme

Comment: @rishiag Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get install -f » but doesnt work when I tried apt-get install -f because say  Can not write to / var / cache / apt /

Comment: In most things I try to install says wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and architecture?

Comment: After solving your issue please read this to correctly install Wine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't read Spanish (I guess) and since you tagged `wine`, then probably you didn't follow the correct procedures to install wine from PPA.

**To install wine from command line**:

1- Open a terminal and add the wine Ubunutu PPA (Personal Package Archive) by typing
 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
2- Then, perform an update to the list of archives by typing `sudo apt-get update`
3- Wine should now be in the list, install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

*Note:* wine1.7 is the latest version, I use 1.6 version. you can choose your wine version before installing by pressing **Tab** after typing `sudo apt-get install wine`

Comment: not work in the second command me appeared the message wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386...In most things I try to install says wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! I typed `upgrade` instead of `update`. I fixed it now.

Comment: I changed to upgrade and the same jeeje.. !!

Comment: No, amigo. Type `update` not `upgrade`.

Comment: Ok ... I changed and now says this ... The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
  wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1: 1.6.1-0ubuntu1 PPA1 ~ ~ precise1) but it is not installable 
  wine1.7: Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1: 1.7.18-0ubuntu1) but will not be installed 
            Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1: 1.7.18-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable 
            Conflicts: wine1.6 but 1: 1.6.1-0ubuntu1 ~ ~ precise1 PPA1 will be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

First of all close the terminal, Ubuntu Software Centre & Synaptics. Now open a terminal and try these steps:

```
sudo apt-get purge moka-gtk-theme wine1.6
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
sudo apt-get install moka-gtk-theme
```

Post any error you get in any of the command.

Comment: Not able to locate the speck-gtk-theme package in the first command

Comment: Leave the first command out and start with the second one.

Comment: Only these are working 
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Please give the exact error you are getting on sudo apt-get install wine1.6?

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
  wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1: 1.6.1-0ubuntu1 PPA1 ~ ~ precise1) but it is not installable 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Is your ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit and which version?

Comment: Sorry, I will update info but is 64 bit 12.04LTS

Comment: Have you already tried sudo apt-get f install? I think your best bet is this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/190424/205030 Do let me know if you face any difficulty in trying that answer.

Comment: Yes I used sudo apt-get f install but doesnt work ... Ok I will see and try...