# Can't Install wine without dependencies

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

Followed [this guide](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) to install `wine`.

After adding `repository` installed `wine` using:

`sudo apt-get install wine1.7`

But I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wine1.7 : Depends:
wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.34-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not installable E:
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
```

But it did not work.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: run apt-get install -f

Comment: Thanks, but did not work

Comment: Same or different error ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/138530/why-do-i-get-an-unmet-dependencies-error-when-trying-to-install-wine and / or contact the maintainer of the ppa as the packager should resolve this problem.

Comment: So when you install wine1.7-i386 what actually occurs, it counted back with the first error? Possibly related to the ppa bot having the desires files or may be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Worked

Comment: hate how the answer was right "in my face"